# Move function for connect four places the move on an entire column instead of only the lowest possible spot

Tags: python

I am in the process of making a connect four game in python and I am at the point where I am making the function to allow the player to make a move. Here is the code I have so far.

```
#myBoard is a 2d array storing the board. col is the column a player is                                                           
#trying to move, and player is the player to move. If it is a valid move,                                                         
#the program will go ahead and change myBoard.                                                                                    
def move2(myBoard, col, player):
     if player == True:
         for i in range(len(myBoard) - 1,-1,-1):
             if myBoard[i][col] == 0:
                 myBoard[i][col] = 1
                 player = False
                 break
     else:
         for i in range(len(myBoard) - 1,-1,-1):
            if myBoard[i][col] == 0:
                myBoard[i][col] = -1
                player = True
                break
     return myBoard, player


#Returns false for now. will return 1 if player 1 has won, a -1 if player 2 has won, and 0 otherwise.                             
#lastColPlayed is the last valid move that was made.                                                                              
def checkWin(myBoard, lastColPlayed):
    return False

#prints myBoard to the screen                                                                                                     
def printBoard(myBoard):
    for row in myBoard:
        for item in row:
            if item == 0:
                print("_", end="")
            elif item == -1:
                print("0", end="")
            elif item == 1:
                print("X", end="")
        print()

#returns true if it's a draw                                                                                                      
def isDraw(myBoard):
    return False

def main():
    player1turn = True
    print("Welcome to Connect Four!")
    rows = input("Please enter a number of rows: ")
    check = True
    while check == True:
        try:
            if int(rows) <= 5:
                while int(rows) <= 5:
                    rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
            else:
                check = False
        except ValueError:
rows = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
    columns = input("Please enter a number of columns: ")
    check2 = True
    while check2 == True:
        try:
            if int(columns) <= 5:
                while int(columns) <= 5:
                    columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
            else:
                check2 = False
        except ValueError:
            columns = input("Please enter a Valid choice: ")
    myBoard = []
    myBoardTemp = []
    for i in range(int(columns)):
        myBoardTemp.append(0)
    for i in range(int(rows)):
        myBoard.append(myBoardTemp)
    printBoard(myBoard)
    check3 = True
    while not checkWin(myBoard, 0) and not isDraw(myBoard):
        move = input("Please enter a move: ")
        while check3 == True:
            try:
                if int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                    while int(move) < 0 or int(move) > len(myBoard[0]):
                        move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
else:
                    check3 = False
            except ValueError:
                move = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")
        myBoard, player1turn = move2(myBoard,int(move) - 1,player1turn)
        printBoard(myBoard)
main()
```

Instead of working properly, this is what happens.

```
Welcome to Connect Four!
Please enter a number of rows: 6
Please enter a number of columns: 20
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
____________________
Please enter a move: 2
_X__________________
_X__________________
_X__________________
_X__________________
_X__________________
_X__________________
Please enter a move: 3
_X0_________________
_X0_________________
_X0_________________
_X0_________________
_X0_________________
_X0_________________
Please enter a move:
```

Does it have something to do with the way I made the board? Are each of the rows "pointing" to one row? how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in your setup:

```
for i in range(int(rows)):
    myBoard.append(myBoardTemp)
```

you have added the *same list* to your board multiple times. That means if you alter that list, it is altered for every row in your board.

Rather than that, add a *different* list for each row in your grid.

```
for i in range(int(rows)):
    myBoard.append([0]*int(columns))
```

Or, more concisely:

```
rows = int(rows)
columns = int(columns)
myBoard = [ [0]*columns for _ in range(rows) ]
```